# Can I force get_option to go back to the DB instead of cache?

Tags: cache, options

Is there any way to guarantee that when I call get_option I will definitely get the value from the database and not from cache?

Comment: I asked the same question on WordPress support forum. Adding it here for future reference - https://wordpress.org/support/topic/force-get_option-to-read-from-the-db-instead-of-cache/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could delete an existing cache for your option before you call `get_option()`:

```
$GLOBALS['wp_object_cache']->delete( 'your_option_name', 'options' );
$value = get_option( 'your_option_name' );
```

Comment: not `wp_cache_delete()`?

Answer (score 7):

Using the wp_cache_delete() technic showcased by toscho, you also have to make sure your option is not on autoload. If your option is autoloaded, it'll be part of the `alloptions` cache so you won't be able to clear it individually.

So make sure to use the following format when you set/update your option if you want to be able to clear it from the cache:

```
update_option( 'my_key', 'my val', false ); // False being the autoload parameter

add_option( 'my_key', 'my val', null, false ); // null is a deprecated argument.
```

[update_option() documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option)

Answer (score 0):

Bit old question but I'll add my piece of information.

I'm using WP REDIS CACHE and notified that some of my `get_option` were returning a cached value, instead of the real DB value. I tried @fuxia solution, but I guess this concerns autoloading. And REDIS cache was applying cache on a "lower level".

I ended up with something to directly get some of my option from DB so I'm sure the value is correct: (in this example, my option name is `my_option_name`)

```
function bypass_cache_custom_options_key($val, $opt)
{
    try {
        global $wpdb;
        $query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->options WHERE " . $wpdb->options . ".option_name = '$opt'");

        return $query[ 0 ]->option_value;
    } catch (Exception $e) {

    }

    return $val;
}

add_filter('pre_option_my_option_name', 'bypass_cache_custom_options_key', 1, 2);
```

see [pre_get_option](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_option_option/)